# Add a material design style label to vuejs3-datepicker

Tags: datepicker, vuetifyjs3

I am using Vuetify3 and want to add label to [vuejs3-datepicker](https://github.com/shubhadip/vuejs3-datepicker) like v-text-field. I have try this but it doesn't work well that datepicker goes second layer.

Code:

```
  <v-text-field label="Date" outlined>
    <Datepicker :v-model="vModel" />
  </v-text-field>
```

Thanks
Wilson